# Chrome 81+ Turn Off Auto Image Rotation Due to EXIF data in img and background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

In Chrome v81+, images are auto-rotated due to EXIF data. I would like to disable this. Setting `image-rotation:none` doesn't do anything in either  or  elements. How can I do this?